# count occurrences matching partial string by column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

new_data is a pandas dataframe with 4 columns and:

If I want to get a count of occurrences for an exact matching by column I do this:

```
new_data[new_data == 'blank'].count()
```

Output:

```
A          0
B          0
C          0
D          2654
```

What if I want a partial match for the string 'bla', would be something like this:

```
new_data[new_data in 'bla'].count()
```

But of course that does not work.
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: `new_data.str.contains('bla')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `sum` for count `True`s:

```
np.random.seed(1234)

new_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['a blas', 's'], size=(2,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (new_data)
        A       B       C  D
0       s       s  a blas  s
1  a blas  a blas  a blas  s

print (new_data.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('bla')).sum())
A    1
B    1
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```

Your solution:

```
print (new_data[new_data.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('bla'))].count())
A    1
B    1
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Remember that new_data is a pandas dataframe, so it does not have the 'str' attribute

Comment: @MiguelSantos - Added `col` for check column by name

Comment: I edited the question, was not clear, I want it for every column

Comment: do you know any solution that might be more clean and general? Because this will not work if you have different types of columns for exemple integers. And the first example with a full match comparison will work for everything

Comment: @MiguelSantos - Unfortunately only `(new_data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('bla')).sum())` - with convert to strings